# How to add/include a picture/image in Telegram's Instant View?

Tags: telegram

I have made a Telegram's Instant View template for a WordPress blog and it's been really easy. However, that blog's articles include pictures that Instant View doesn't show. I need to know how I add them to the Instant View template.

I know I have to use "@append" or "@prepend" but don't know really how.

Thanks for reading!

```
@append
@prepend
```

Comment: That really depends on the markup, can you paste it in the question? Also, can you share you code of markup and a link to some page with images missing?